# MessageKit InputBar is hidden/removed on ViewController dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview, messagekit, inputbaraccessoryview

I am using MessageKit `3.0.0-swift5` branch for chats.
Clicking on the message, I am presenting the ViewController.
When Viewcontroller is dismissed, I am not able to access InputBar.

Has anybody come across this issue?

Check the video [here](https://youtu.be/mrs1TPPH-Fk).

Code:

```
// MessageCellDelegate

func didTapMessage(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) { 
     self.showFileInBrowser(withTitle: "", url: fileURL)
}

func showFileInBrowser(withTitle title: String? = nil,  url: URL) {
     self.fileBrowser = FileBrowserViewController(title: title, url: url)
     let navigation = BaseNavigationController(rootViewController: fileBrowser!)
     self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// FileBrowserViewController

@objc func closeButtonTapped() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am also using **IQKeyboardManager**, but the below solution is not working.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = false
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my application, which is using just `InputBarViewController` (in some reasons I had to implement my own chat, not using MessageKit).

So, this issue is very easy to reproduce if you are trying to show some modal view controller not from current controller, or even moving first responder focus to another `UITextField` within current VC (e.g. search field).
For me working solution is just call `becomeFirstResponder` on current view controller instance just after resigning control from search field or inside `viewDidAppear` (or in some other place where you can be sure, chat UI is visible again).

P.S. I also faced this issue when `UIContextMenu` (long touch in cell) was dismissed. Solution was pretty the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to before present the next ViewController disable Keyboard by `TextView.resignFirstResponder()` Because the problem begins while ViewController is Presenting

Comment: If you still have problem let me know to find solution

Comment: dismissing keyboard is not working. This is very random behavior.

Comment: I am using JSQ, but same issue. InputToolBar disappears after presenting native Camera app. Calling resignFirstResponder does nothing as the ViewController resigns first responder as a new ViewController is presented and at the same time inputToolBar gets dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

I too facing that issue before, but i tried to to present `nextViewController` as by adding the following code. hope it will work.

```
 nextViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
 nextViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
```

Comment: I am using JSQ, but same issue. InputToolBar disappears after presenting native Camera app.